# Making a responsive jQuery mobile menu button work on all small screen pages?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, navbar, responsive

i'm a beginner using a responsive jQuery mobile menu for my main nav bar. The mobile menu button (three horizontal lines) on the small screen works on the first page loaded, but then reverts to the original navbar (see image below). Is there a way to run the code multiple times so that it runs on each page every time? Thanks for your time!

The relevant code is below...

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
      
      var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        breakpoint: 768,
        sticky: false
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {
        cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
        if (settings.format != 'select') {
          cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
          $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
            var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
            if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
              mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
            }
            else {
              mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
              if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                mainmenu.find('ul').show();
              }
            }
          });

          multiTg = function() {
            cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
            cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
              $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
              if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
              }
              else {
                $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
              }
            });
          };

          if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
          else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
        }

        else if (settings.format === 'select')
        {
          cssmenu.append('<select style="width: 100%"/>').addClass('select-list');
          var selectList = cssmenu.find('select');
          selectList.append('<option>' + settings.title + '</option>', {
                                                         "selected": "selected",
                                                         "value": ""});
          cssmenu.find('a').each(function() {
            var element = $(this), indentation = "";
            for (i = 1; i < element.parents('ul').length; i++)
            {
              indentation += '-';
            }
            selectList.append('<option value="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">' + indentation + element.text() + '</option');
          });
          selectList.on('change', function() {
            window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
          });
        }

        if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

        resizeFix = function() {
          if ($(window).width() > settings.breakpoint) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').show();
            cssmenu.removeClass('small-screen');
            if (settings.format === 'select') {
              cssmenu.find('select').hide();
            }
            else {
              cssmenu.find("#menu-button").removeClass("menu-opened");
            }
          }

          if ($(window).width() <= settings.breakpoint && !cssmenu.hasClass("small-screen")) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
            cssmenu.addClass('small-screen');
            if (settings.format === 'select') {
              cssmenu.find('select').show();
            }
          }
        };
        resizeFix();
        return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

      });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
    title: "Menu",
    format: "dropdown"
  });

  $("#cssmenu a").each(function() {
   var linkTitle = $(this).text();
   $(this).attr('data-title', linkTitle);
  });
});

});
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #dff2fa;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -ms-transform: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  color: #059;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  content: attr(data-title);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(- -18px);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a::before,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover::before {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: black;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a::before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #e9e9e9;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 17px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  width: 22px;
  height: 3px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 27px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
  background: black;
}

#sessionrecord img,
#login img,
#email img,
#viewsessions img,
#register img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#home img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 20px; 
  margin-bottom: -30px;
}

.ui-page .ui-footer p {
    margin-left: 77%;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1; minimum-scale=1;">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <link href="/projects/ibill_v3/css/mainstyles.css" rel="StyleSheet"/>
  <link href="/projects/ibill_v3/css/register.css" rel="StyleSheet"/>
  <link href="/projects/ibill_v3/css/login.css" rel="StyleSheet"/>
  <link href="/projects/ibill_v3/css/home.css" rel="StyleSheet"/>
  <link href="/projects/ibill_v3/css/record_session.css" rel="StyleSheet"/>
  <link href="/projects/ibill_v3/css/viewsessions.css" rel="StyleSheet"/>
  <link href="/projects/ibill_v3/css/email.css" rel="StyleSheet"/>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).on('pageinit', function(){
                $('#registerForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
                    // rules & options
                });
            });  
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).on('pageinit', function(){
                $('.loginform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
                    // rules & options
                });
            });  
  </script>

</head>

<body>
 <!--********************************REGISTER PAGE**********************************************-->
<!--****************************************************************************************-->

<!--********************************HEADER**********************************************-->
<div data-role="page" id="register">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
    <div id='cssmenu'>
      <ul>
         <li class='active'><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
         <li><a href='#sessionrecord'>Record a Session</a></li>
         <li><a href='#viewsessions'>View Sessions</a></li>
         <li><a href='#email'>E-mail an Invoice</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--********************************HEADER**********************************************-->

<!--********************************MAIN**********************************************-->
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    
    <img class="mainlogo" src="/projects/ibill_v3/img/ibill logo.png" alt="iBill Logo" width="250" height="190">
        <section class="registerform">
          <h1>The iBill Invoicing App for Activity Instructors</h1>
          <p>Register below</p>
              <form action="register.php" id="registerForm">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="required" minlength="5" placeholder="enter username (min-5 characters)">
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="required" minlength="5" placeholder="enter firstname">
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <label for="username">Surname</label>
                    <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" class="required" minlength="5" placeholder="enter surname">
                  </li>

                  <li> 
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="required email" placeholder="yourname@email.com">
                  </li>

                  <li> 
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required" minlength="6" placeholder="enter password">
                  </li>

                  <li> 
                    <label for="confirmpassword">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" class="required" minlength="6" placeholder="re-enter password">
                  </li>
                <div id="registerbutton">
                      <input type="submit" value="Register">
                </div>
                </ul>
              </form>
        </section>

  </div>
<!--********************************MAIN**********************************************-->

<!--********************************FOOTER**********************************************-->
  <div data-role="footer">
    <footer class="footer">
        <p>awilliams&copy;</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
<!--********************************REGISTER PAGE**********************************************-->
<!--****************************************************************************************-->
 


<!--********************************LOGIN PAGE**********************************************-->
<!--****************************************************************************************-->

<!--********************************HEADER**********************************************-->
<div data-role="page" id="login">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
    <div id='cssmenu'>
      <ul>
         <li class='active'><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
         <li><a href='#sessionrecord'>Record a Session</a></li>
         <li><a href='#viewsessions'>View Sessions</a></li>
         <li><a href='#email'>E-mail an Invoice</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--********************************HEADER**********************************************-->

<!--********************************MAIN**********************************************-->
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    
    <img class="mainlogo" src="/projects/ibill_v3/img/ibill logo.png" alt="iBill Logo" width="250" height="190">
        
        <section class="loginform">
              <form action="form.php" method="post"> 
                  <ul>
                    <li><label for="usermail">Email</label>
                      <input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" class="required"></li>
                    <li><label for="password">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter password"  minlength="6"></li>
                    <li>
                    <div id="loginbutton">
                      <input type="submit" value="Login"></li>
                    </div>
                    <div id="registerbutton">
                      <input type="submit" value="Register"></li>
                    </div>
                  </ul>
              </form>
        </section>

  </div>
<!--********************************MAIN**********************************************-->

<!--********************************FOOTER**********************************************-->
  <div data-role="footer">
    <footer class="footer">
        <p>awilliams&copy;</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
<!--********************************LOGIN PAGE**********************************************-->
<!--****************************************************************************************-->

<!--********************************HOME PAGE**********************************************-->
<!--***************************************************************************************-->

<!--********************************HEADER**********************************************-->
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
    <div id='cssmenu'>
     <ul>
        <li class='active'><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
           <li><a href='#sessionrecord'>Record a Session</a></li>
           <li><a href='#viewsessions'>View Sessions</a></li>
           <li><a href='#email'>E-mail an Invoice</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    </div><!-- /header -->
<!--********************************HEADER**********************************************-->

<!--********************************MAIN**********************************************-->
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    
    <img class="mainlogo" src="/projects/ibill_v3/img/ibill logo.png" alt="iBill Logo" width="250" height="190">
        
        <section class="maincontent">
                <h1>The iBill Invoicing App for Activity Instructors</h1>
                  <p>iBill is a cross-platform app that allows you track and manage activity sessions on the go.</p>
                  <br> 
                  <p>Record an activity session to get started!</p>
                <div style="text-align:center">
                  <a href="#sessionrecord" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Record a Session</a>
                </div>
        </section>
  </div>
<!--********************************MAIN**********************************************-->

<!--********************************FOOTER**********************************************-->
  <div data-role="footer">
    <footer class="footer">
        <p>awilliams&copy;</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
<!--********************************FOOTER**********************************************-->

<!--********************************HOME PAGE**********************************************-->
<!--***************************************************************************************-->

<!--********************************RECORD SESSION PAGE************************************-->
<!--***************************************************************************************-->

<!--********************************HEADER**********************************************-->
<div data-role="page" id="sessionrecord">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
    <div id='cssmenu'>
      <ul>
        <li class='active'><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#sessionrecord'>Record a Session</a></li>
        <li><a href='#viewsessions'>View Sessions</a></li>
        <li><a href='#email'>E-mail an Invoice</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /header -->
<!--********************************HEADER**********************************************-->

<!--********************************MAIN**********************************************-->
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    
    <img class="mainlogo" src="/projects/ibill_v3/img/ibill logo.png" alt="iBill Logo" width="250" height="190">
        
        <section class="maincontent">
          <h1>Record a session using the form below</h1>
            <form method="post" action="PHP HERE" id="sessionRecord">
              <fieldset>
                  <select name="typeofactivity" id="typeofactivity" data-native-menu="false">
                    <option>Type of Session</option>
                    <option value="surf">Surf</option>
                    <option value="coast">Coasteer</option>
                    <option value="bodyboard">Bodyboard</option>
                    <option value="climbing">Cornish Challenge</option>
                  </select>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>
                  <select name="employer" id="employer" data-native-menu="false">
                    <option>Employer</option>
                    <option value="nac">Newquay Activity Centre</option>
                    <option value="coastline">Coastline Coasteer</option>
                  </select>
              </fieldset>
              <form method="post" action="PHP HERE!">
                  <label for="datetime">Date and Time of Session</label>
                  <input type="datetime-local" data-clear-btn="false" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="">
              </form>
              <form method="post" action="PHP HERE!">
                  <label for="amount">Amount (GBP)</label>
                  <input type="number" data-clear-btn="true" name="amount" id="amount" value="">
              </form>
                <div id="submitbutton">
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </form>

        </section>
  </div>
<!--********************************MAIN**********************************************-->

<!--********************************FOOTER**********************************************-->
  <div data-role="footer">
    <footer class="footer">
        <p>awilliams&copy;</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
<!--********************************FOOTER**********************************************-->

<!--********************************RECORD SESSION PAGE************************************-->
<!--***************************************************************************************-->

<!--********************************VIEW SESSIONS PAGE************************************-->
<!--***************************************************************************************-->

<!--********************************HEADER**********************************************-->
<div data-role="page" id="viewsessions">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
    <div id='cssmenu'>
      <ul>
         <li class='active'><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
         <li><a href='#sessionrecord'>Record a Session</a></li>
         <li><a href='#viewsessions'>View Sessions</a></li>
         <li><a href='#email'>E-mail an Invoice</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /header -->
<!--********************************HEADER**********************************************-->

<!--********************************MAIN**********************************************-->
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    
    <img class="mainlogo" src="/projects/ibill_v3/img/ibill logo.png" alt="iBill Logo" width="250" height="190">
        
        <section class="maincontent">
                <!--MAIN CONTENT GOES HERE-->
        </section>
  </div>
<!--********************************MAIN**********************************************-->

<!--********************************FOOTER**********************************************-->
  <div data-role="footer">
    <footer class="footer">
        <p>awilliams&copy;</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
<!--********************************FOOTER**********************************************-->

<!--********************************VIEW SESSIONS PAGE************************************-->
<!--***************************************************************************************-->


<!--********************************EMAIL AN INVOICE PAGE************************************-->
<!--***************************************************************************************-->

<!--********************************HEADER**********************************************-->
<div data-role="page" id="email">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
    <div id='cssmenu'>
      <ul>
         <li class='active'><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
         <li><a href='#sessionrecord'>Record a Session</a></li>
         <li><a href='#viewsessions'>View Sessions</a></li>
         <li><a href='#email'>E-mail an Invoice</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /header -->
<!--********************************HEADER**********************************************-->

<!--********************************MAIN**********************************************-->
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    
    <img class="mainlogo" src="/projects/ibill_v3/img/ibill logo.png" alt="iBill Logo" width="250" height="190">
        
        <section class="maincontent">
                <!--MAIN CONTENT GOES HERE-->
        </section>
  </div>
<!--********************************MAIN**********************************************-->

<!--********************************FOOTER**********************************************-->
  <div data-role="footer">
    <footer class="footer">
        <p>awilliams&copy;</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
<!--********************************FOOTER**********************************************-->

<!--********************************EMAIL AN INVOICE PAGE************************************-->
<!--***************************************************************************************-->

</body>
```

Comment: There is nothing in the code that determines when to add the class "small-screen" to the cssmenu element.

Comment: So i noticed that the small screen menu bar works when the page has just been refreshed, but as soon as a link is clicked, it doesn't work. Why does it work initially, and then stop?

Comment: I have created this simple page based on the code that you have posted, and it does not work initially, unless the class "small-screen" is manually added to the cssmenu element, and so I assume you have not posted some relevant code :) https://www.elitesystemer.no/demo/test/36425479/

Comment: Hi Gjermund Dahl, apologies, I didn't include the javascript file for jquery mobile. I have edited the post to include all the pages in a single HTML file  and tried to explain it a little better. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: It looks like you end up with one page with multiple elements with the same ID (id="cssmenu"). That won't work. Element IDs must be unique within a HTML document.

Comment: I have posted a formal answer below and corrected your code in this demo: https://www.elitesystemer.no/demo/test/36425479/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, ID tags should be unique with the HTML doc. Working solution:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {

      var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        breakpoint: 768,
        sticky: false
      }, options);

      //return this.each(function() {
        cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
        if (settings.format != 'select') {
          cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
          $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
            var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
            if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
              mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
            }
            else {
              mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
              if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                mainmenu.find('ul').show();
              }
            }
          });

          multiTg = function() {
            cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
            cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
              $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
              if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
              }
              else {
                $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
              }
            });
          };

          if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
          else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
        }

        else if (settings.format === 'select')
        {
          cssmenu.append('<select style="width: 100%"/>').addClass('select-list');
          var selectList = cssmenu.find('select');
          selectList.append('<option>' + settings.title + '</option>', {
                                                         "selected": "selected",
                                                         "value": ""});
          cssmenu.find('a').each(function() {
            var element = $(this), indentation = "";
            for (i = 1; i < element.parents('ul').length; i++)
            {
              indentation += '-';
            }
            selectList.append('<option value="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">' + indentation + element.text() + '</option');
          });
          selectList.on('change', function() {
            window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
          });
        }

        if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

        resizeFix = function() {
          if ($(window).width() > settings.breakpoint) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').show();
            cssmenu.removeClass('small-screen');
            if (settings.format === 'select') {
              cssmenu.find('select').hide();
            }
            else {
              cssmenu.find("#menu-button").removeClass("menu-opened");
            }
          }

          if ($(window).width() <= settings.breakpoint && !cssmenu.hasClass("small-screen")) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
            cssmenu.addClass('small-screen');
            if (settings.format === 'select') {
              cssmenu.find('select').show();
            }
          }
        };
        resizeFix();

        return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
    };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".cssmenu").menumaker({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown"
      });

      $(".cssmenu a").each(function() {
        var linkTitle = $(this).text();
        $(this).attr('data-title', linkTitle);
      });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Change all

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
```

to

```
<div class='cssmenu'>
```

and update you CSS:

```
.cssmenu,
.cssmenu ul,
.cssmenu ul li,
.cssmenu ul li a,
.cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cssmenu:after,
.cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
.cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}
.cssmenu > ul {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
.cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: black;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
.cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #dff2fa;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -ms-transform: none;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > a::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  color: black;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  content: attr(data-title);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(- -18px);
}
.cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a::before,
.cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover::before {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}
.cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}
.cssmenu.small-screen > ul,
.cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
.cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li,
.cssmenu.small-screen.align-center {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
}
.cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li:hover > a,
.cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: black;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
}
.cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a::before {
  display: none;
}
.cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #e9e9e9;
}
.cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 17px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  width: 22px;
  height: 3px;
}
.cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 27px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
}
.cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
  background: black;
}

#sessionrecord img,
#home img,
#login img,
#email img,
#viewsessions img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.ui-page .ui-footer p {
    margin-left: 77%;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gjermund, i changed it around and it worked. I knew it was something to do with the id only being called once, but couldn't figure it out. I have learnt a lot from this... Thanks again :)